# Блоки едут друг на друга при изменении масштаба страницы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Попробовал поверстать немного, есть вопросы по резиновой верстке.

Имеется следующий макет и несколько вопросов:

[image]

Масштаб: 100%, все, казалось бы, идеально.

Далее, переходим к масштабу 300%:

[image]

Происходит непонятная для меня ситуация (в данный момент). Два блока едут друг на друга, хотелось бы, чтобы они как-то адаптировались под масштаб. Ведь так, наверно, не должно быть.

Полный CSS+HTML шаблоны сохранил здесь: http://cssdesk.com/GnGvu

Очень надеюсь, что кто-нибудь поможет, и объяснит, почему и как.

Заранее благодарен.

**UPD1**: убрал абсолютную позицию с .main-nav, теперь, вроде как, заезжает дальше логотипа, однако, как-то скочит при изменениях масштаба, так и должно быть? Если поставить margin: 2.5% 10%, вместо right, top позиционирования с абсолютной позицией, то он при масштабировании уезжает вниз, на 300% приезжает вверх. Обновил версию на cssdesk.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте оборачивать контейнеры которым вы задаёте ширину в процентах ещё во внешние контейнеры, должно помочь

Comment: @santer545, нет, к сожалению, все по-прежнему.

Немного обновил пост. (UPD1)